# Can a "punctured" plastic bumper be repaired?

Tags: body-work, body, bumper, plastic, body-filler

My dad's car was hit in a parking lot and there are 2 holes or "punctures" in it from the numberplate bolts on the offending car.

The holes are about 10mm (.4 inch) diameter.

I've used bumper repair filler before but feel it wouldn't be good for this size (as it cracks when flexes).

Can anyone recommend a product or technique for repairing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get what is called a "[plastic welder](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=abs+plastic+welder+kit&crid=2AEBP354MHXZR&ref=nb_sb_ss_shopnav-of-top-exp_5)". I've never used one so don't know the "proper" usage of it, but I'm sure if you looked it up on YouTube you can find all kinds of advice for running one. The basics of using one is pretty much introducing filler plastic, melting it with the welder, fill the hole, wait for it to cool, then sand to flat, & finish as needed.